# Correct way to animate big amounts of data on Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm working on a project that involves dozens of files every file has on it hundreds of points and each file represents a line on matplotlib, this files will be updating automatically by another software, my goal is to be constantly ploting the content of them, the first kind of file has this format:

```
"Convergence history of Static Temperature on p14 (in SI units)"
"Iteration" "Vertex Average Static Temperature"
10 358.3162536621094
20 369.484375
30 375.3867797851562
40 378.8209228515625
50 380.5880432128906
60 381.4667663574219
70 381.8531494140625
80 381.9440307617188
...
```

First number represents `"X"` axis and second `"Y"`, this are the `".out"`, it is easy to parse the data of these ones and even animate them.

The other kind of file with the following format contains 5 lines to be plotted on matplotlib, that has the following format:

```
1 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 0.0000e+00} {y-velocity 4.3827e-02} {z-velocity 1.9319e-03} {energy 1.2276e-07} }
2 {{continuity 1.0000e+00} {x-velocity 7.8061e-04} {y-velocity 1.6308e+01} {z-velocity 1.0320e-03} {energy 2.9296e-06} }
3 {{continuity 2.3509e-01} {x-velocity 1.2848e-03} {y-velocity 1.2352e-02} {z-velocity 1.0337e-02} {energy 2.2715e-06} }
4 {{continuity 8.0945e-02} {x-velocity 1.6650e-03} {y-velocity 1.3073e-02} {z-velocity 1.0491e-02} {energy 3.2993e-07} }
```

The first number represents the `"X"` axis and every line/name in between the braces `"{}"` has it's  `"Y "` value, the extension of these are `".res"` and I'm using regex to parse their data.

**Expected Behavior**

The code is supposed to read all files, sort them by category, then I'll call the animate function on every category, the animate function will read every file on the category, and plot it to a matplotlib graph, every x amount of time.

**Problem**

The code right now works partially, because it's really inefficient, it doesn't even completes reading all files that it needs to plot before the animate function want's to execute again, i believe regex it's a big problem here, since  it's slower, and i need to find a way to read just the newest point and not re-plot all files.

- *Should i aim to have a higher the amount of time between animations?*
- *Should i call animate on every file instead of every category?
  (I maybe have around 20-30 animate functions running simultaneously)* Is that bad?
- *Should i use threading in order to improve the performance?*
- *Am i facing a limitation of matplotlib animation function or just doing a bad implementation?*

---

**Code:**

*Function that finds the files to be plotted.*

```
def find_plot_files(self, file_path, n):
    project_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]  # Erase everything before the last slash:  /ab/bc/tu.out > tu.out
    project_name = project_name[:project_name.find(".")]
    current_project = self.controller.project_list.create_project(project_name, file_path)
    file_path = os.path.dirname(file_path)

    for file in os.listdir(file_path):
        graph_name = file[file.find(".") + 1:file.rfind(".")]
        if file.endswith(".out"):
            if project_name in file:
                current_file = open(file_path + "/" + file, 'r').read()
                if 'Temperature' in current_file:
                    current_project.insert_graph('Temperature', graph_name, file_path+"/"+file)
                elif 'Pressure' in current_file:
                    current_project.insert_graph('Pressure', graph_name, file_path+"/"+file)
                elif 'Velocity' in current_file:
                    current_project.insert_graph('Velocity', graph_name, file_path+"/"+file)
        elif file.endswith(".res"):
            if project_name in file:
                current_project.insert_graph('Residuals', graph_name, file_path+"/"+file)

#Here every "graph" represents a category, and i will create a figure and plot every line into it.

    for graph in self.controller.project_list.get_project(project_name).get_graphs():
        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        f.suptitle(graph)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.animated_graph.append(animation.FuncAnimation(f, self.animate, fargs=(a, project_name, graph),
                                                           interval=3000))
```

*Animate function*

```
def animate(self, i, target_graph, project_name, graph):
    target_graph.clear()
    for graph in self.controller.project_list.get_project(project_name).get_graphs()[graph]:
        file_path = graph.file_path
        pull_data = open(file_path, 'r').read()
        data_array = pull_data.split('\n')
        xar = []
        # THIS PLOTS THE SECOND CASE THAT I COPIED IN THE QUESTION
        if graph.file_path[-3:] == 'res':
            lines_list = {}
            for each_line in data_array:
                if len(each_line) > 0:
                    xar.append(each_line[0:each_line.find(" ")])
                    each_line = each_line[each_line.find(" ")+2: -1]
                    for data_point in re.findall("\{(.*?)\}", each_line):
                        data_point = data_point.split()
                        if data_point[0] in lines_list:
                            lines_list[data_point[0]].append(data_point[1])
                        else:
                            lines_list[data_point[0]] = [data_point[1]]
            for key in lines_list:
                target_graph.plot(xar, lines_list[key], label=key)
        else:
            # THIS PLOTS THE FIRST CASE THAT I COPIED IN THE QUESTION
            yar = []
            for each_line in data_array:
                try:
                    if len(each_line.split()) == 2:
                        x, y = each_line.split()
                        xar.append(float(x))
                        yar.append(float(y))
                except TypeError:
                    pass
            target_graph.plot(xar, yar)
```

I'm really new using matplotlib and animate function, so any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd like comments with downvotes, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are asking several questions and I'm not an animation expert, please let me give a first hint for reading in the data:

Perhaps it's faster to rely on importer functions of available python packages, which are optimized for those tasks like the ones of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

That would be for your '.out'-files quite simple:

```
In:pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=1, sep=' ')
Out: 
   Iteration  Vertex Average Static Temperature
0         10                         358.316254
1         20                         369.484375
2         30                         375.386780
3         40                         378.820923
4         50                         380.588043
5         60                         381.466766
6         70                         381.853149
7         80                         381.944031
```

The '.res'-files look more complex, but you can first have a look at them like:

```
pd.read_table(filename, names=None, sep='[{}\s]+', engine='python')

   1  continuity  1.0000e+00  x-velocity  0.0000e+00  y-velocity  4.3827e-02  \
0  2  continuity    1.000000  x-velocity    0.000781  y-velocity   16.308000   
1  3  continuity    0.235090  x-velocity    0.001285  y-velocity    0.012352   
2  4  continuity    0.080945  x-velocity    0.001665  y-velocity    0.013073   

   z-velocity  1.9319e-03  energy    1.2276e-07  Unnamed: 11  
0  z-velocity    0.001032  energy  2.929600e-06          NaN  
1  z-velocity    0.010337  energy  2.271500e-06          NaN  
2  z-velocity    0.010491  energy  3.299300e-07          NaN
```

From this result you can retrieve the column numbers you're interested in and use this information for the import in the future:

```
pd.read_table(filename, usecols=[2,4,6,8,10], names=['x', 'x-vel', 'y-vel', 'z-vel', 'energy'], sep='[{}\s]+', engine='python')

          x     x-vel      y-vel     z-vel        energy
0  1.000000  0.000000   0.043827  0.001932  1.227600e-07
1  1.000000  0.000781  16.308000  0.001032  2.929600e-06
2  0.235090  0.001285   0.012352  0.010337  2.271500e-06
3  0.080945  0.001665   0.013073  0.010491  3.299300e-07
```

The results are pandas dataframes, which provide a very large set of functions for further processing, including just accessing a np.array-representation of their values if you prefer.

Perhaps this helps a little.

Comment: That's a wonderful hint, i'll try it and comeback with an opinion.

Comment: I'm having some troubles with the colspecs when the number of points gets too high, it shifts to the right, and the data starts appearing in a wrong format "29    5.3849e-0   1.3535e-0   1.0677e-0   4.2473e-0   6.3448e-0
..          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
970  y 6.2748e-  y 3.1410e-  y 1.4403e-  y 8.5215e-  y 1.7764e-", is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try sth like   `pd.read_table(filename, names=None, sep='[{}\s]+', engine='python')`           sorry, no more time right now... add names afterwards...

Comment: Look at the result and note the numbers oft the columns you need. Then instead of `names=None` use  `usecols=_list_of_numbers_` and `names=_list_oft_names`